# Can I replace 'get started on' with 'start'?

Tags: word-usage

I read this sentence, and I'm curious if it has subtle difference in meaning.

> I should **get started on** that sooner rather than that later.

Can I just say 'I should **start** that on that sooner rather than that later.'?

What is the difference of *get started on* and *start*?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in many contexts (if you delete the errant "that").  Not so much going the other way, as noted in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

In the given example, yes, you can replace *get started on* with *start*.

> I should **start** that sooner rather than <strike>that</strike> later.

However, the two are not always interchangeable. Michael Owen Sartin wrote in a comment:

> There is a slight difference between 'start' and 'start on.'  One can start an engine, and the engine will be running.  If one starts on an engine, the implication is that he is beginning a process such as painting or repairing the engine.

Regarding your sentence though, *[sooner rather than later](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sooner_rather_than_later)* is the usual expression, without the *that* in between.

***Get started on (something)*** is an idiom. -- [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+started+on)

> to begin doing something; to take the first steps to do something.
>   *"When do we get started on this project?"*
>   *"I want to get started on this right away."*

Comment: There is a slight difference between 'start' and 'start on.'  One can start an engine, and the engine will be running.  If one starts on an engine, the implication is that he is beginning a process such as painting or repairing the engine.

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin yes, I'm including your comment in my answer. 

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin I quite agree, but I would also say that _start on_ implies not only a process but also effort and commitment (usually concerted and/or extended effort and commitment) on the part of the speaker. Kicking off an automated process would not be 'getting started on' something unless it was part of a longer process involving human input. For example loading and starting an automatic washing machine would not be 'getting started on the washing' since the machine does most of the work, but it would be 'getting started on the laundry' if the washing also needed ironing.